# Show the DisplayMember according to the ValueMember combobox C#

Tags: c#

I have code that takes data from database, and I get the valuemember as the selected value of combobox, now I want to make it that the combobox to show the item selected according to the valuemember.

Example

```
normal combo

Car -> 1
House -> 2
Tree - >3 


after sql valuemember value is 3

Tree
Car
House
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("D");
dt.Columns.Add("V", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add("Car", 1);
dt.Rows.Add("House", 2);
dt.Rows.Add("Tree", 3);
```

You can:

```
someCombo.DisplayMember = "D";
someCombo.ValueMember = "V";
someCombo.DataSource = dt;
```

And then later, after the user has chosen something, you can:

```
int x = (int)someCombo.SelectedValue;
```

Or you can:

```
DataRow r = ((DataRowView)someCombo.SelectedItem).Row;
var d = r["D"] as string;
var v = (int)r["V"];
```

And so on..